# OFI rdma write immediate failed (ofi_rma.h:436:MPIDI_OFI_do_put:Invalid argument)

Tags: c++, mpi

I am writing  multiple nodes mpi program but plagued with unexplained errors.

```
$ mpirun -ppn 1 -hosts machine1,machine2 ./mpi_multiput

Abort(1008844559) on node 1 (rank 1 in comm 0): Fatal error in PMPI_Put: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Put(160)........: MPI_Put(origin_addr=0x7ffd486fa6b0, origin_count=1, MPI_FLOAT, target_rank=0, target_disp=1, target_count=1, MPI_FLOAT, win=0xa0000000) failed
MPID_Put(795)........: 
MPIDI_put_safe(464)..: 
MPIDI_put_unsafe(42).: 
MPIDI_OFI_do_put(436): OFI rdma write immediate failed (ofi_rma.h:436:MPIDI_OFI_do_put:Invalid argument)
```

I have never seen this error code.

each nodes are connected infiniband and ethernet.

```
mpi_multiput.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int rank, n;
    
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &n);
    
    const int target = 0;
    const int nsend  = 1;
    
    MPI_Win win_header, win_data;
    float* dat;
    MPI_Win_allocate_shared(sizeof(float)*n, sizeof(float), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &dat, &win_data);
  
    int ndat= 0;
    MPI_Win_create(&ndat, sizeof(int), sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win_header);

    MPI_Win_fence(0, win_data);
    int   offset;
    float send = rank + 1.0;

    MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, target, 0, win_header);
    MPI_Get_accumulate(&nsend, 1, MPI_INT, &offset, 1, MPI_INT, target, 0, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, win_header);
    MPI_Win_unlock(target, win_header);
   
    MPI_Put(&send,1,MPI_FLOAT,target,offset,1,MPI_FLOAT,win_data);

    
    MPI_Win_fence(0, win_data);


    if(rank == target) {
        cout << "ndat after communication: " << ndat << endl;
        for(int i=0; i<ndat; ++i)
            cout << "received data[" << i << "] = " << dat[i] << endl;
    }   

    MPI_Win_free(&win_header);
    MPI_Win_free(&win_data);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

non-multiple mpirun is success.

```
$ mpirun -np 2 ./mpi_multiput

ndat after communication: 2
received data[0] = 2
received data[1] = 1
```

also, hello world program is able to run multiple nodes.

What environment variables are required when using MPI_Put?